# Shall we use Quickbooks SDK 8.0 for Quickbooks online?

Tags: quickbooks

I am new to Quickbooks. I want to know whether Quickbooks has any seperate SDK for Online vesrion or shall we use SDK 8 for developing applications for Online version also.

Thanks in Advance
Janu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, use SDK 8. The QuickBooks SDK covers all desktop versions of QuickBooks and Online Edition.

Note that for Online Edition, you don't really need any special SDK at all- you're just simply HTTPS POSTing XML messages to a remote server. The SDK only gets you a few convienence features for .NET languages- namely QBFC classes. For any other language, you won't need the SDK at all. The only other item in the SDK that's sometimes helpful is the XML Validator tool they include with it.

The actual documentation for all of the requests is available online: 
 [QuickBooks OSR Documentation](http://developer.intuit.com/qbsdk-current/common/newosr/index.html)

I have some additional documentation about communicating with QuickBooks Online Edition on my wiki:
 [ConsoliBYTE QuickBooks Wiki](http://wiki.consolibyte.com/wiki/doku.php/quickbooks_online_edition)

Comment: Hi Keith,

Thank you very much your reply. your posts helped me a lot. I am able connect using XML.

Thanks and Regards
Janu